# asp button's onclick event is not working in content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick, master-pages

I've a Master page and few content pages of it. In the content pages, the asp control button is not working in a sense that its onclick event is not firing and executing the code. I've checked each and everything like manually writing the code, checking the javascript etc. Its not even reloading the page when I click on the button. Kindly help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Register" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Join Now" OnClick="Register_Click" />

Comment: I've tried breakpoints as well but the control never gets into the event code.

Comment: Pls check if there is any error in browser's console.

Comment: there is some fonts related error but that font file doesn't exist in my solution.

Comment: Is this button wrapped in a form element?